# How to add a value at the beginning of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add the value 0 at the beginning of an array.

My code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
import loaddataa as ld
import scipy.integrate as integrate 

dataListStride = ld.loadData("../Data/Fabienne")
indexStrideData = 0 
strideData = dataListStride[indexStrideData]

def horizontal(yAngle, yAcceleration, xAcceleration):
    a = (m.cos(yAngle)*yAcceleration)-(m.sin(yAngle)*xAcceleration)
    return a

resultsHorizontal = list()

for i in range (len(strideData)):
    strideData_yAngle = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 2]
    strideData_xAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 4]
    strideData_yAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 5]
    resultsHorizontal.append(horizontal(strideData_yAngle, strideData_yAcceleration, strideData_xAcceleration))

print("The values are: " +str(resultsHorizontal))
```

This is the output after the for - loop: [output array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg4OO.png)
Where the red arrow goes, a 0 should be added. Could someone please tell me how I can reach this? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Use [`np.insert`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html), [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) or [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: Would `resultsHorizontal = [0]` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert things at a specific position in an array, the following command works:

```py
>>>my_array = np.arange(5, 14, 2)
>>>np.insert(my_array, 0, 0)
>>>print(my_array)
[0, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

So you could just use the `np.insert()` command after going through your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could either insert a 0 as suggested by Steven in their answer, or just start with a list which already has a 0 as the first element, like

```
resultsHorizontal = [0]
```

Both approaches would yield the same result